# SyntaxError : Json.parse:unexpected end of data GWT

Tags: java, json, gwt, spring-boot, gwt-2.5

I am getting **"Json.parse:unexpected end of data"** in my client side,When i make rest request to my API using GWT.

Client side code :

```
private void executeUnAccountedTransactionByService(String requestJson)
    {
        String requestData = "request=" + URL.encodeQueryString(requestJson);

        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(postPaymentUrl));

        builder.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        builder.setHeader("Accept","application/json") ;
        try  {

            builder.sendRequest(requestData, new RequestCallback()  {

                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)  {

                    JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(response.getText());
                    JSONObject responseObject = jsonValue.isObject();
                    //my logic
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (RequestException e)  {
        }
    }
```

My API Code :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/url",
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> processPayment(
                                            @RequestParam("request") String payRequestJson,
                                            HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

        PutUnAccountedTransaction unAccountedTransaction = null ;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("request recieved unaccounted transaction : " +
                    payRequestJson);
             unAccountedTransaction = objectMapper.readValue(payRequestJson, PutUnAccountedTransaction.class) ;
       } catch (Exception e) {
          //currenlty handling success case only.
            return ResponseEntity.ok(unAccountedTransaction);
       }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(unAccountedTransaction);
    }
```

The same API I call in postman with following values:
HEADERs :

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

request : `{"applicationIdentiferICC":"jh2b32vy","amount":"100","authCode":"hhbjhbjh","orderNumber":"jhsbhjb","dateTimeInUTC":"03/01/2017 07:20:57","gatewayName":"gatewayname","transactionReference":"asdhgwvg","dealerId":"bhjhahdbj","cardType":"VISA","terminalId":"jjhbjhbhjbj","userReference":"bjhbjh","paymentType":"EMV_CHIP","expMonth":"09","expYear":"19","cardNumber":"1111"}`

and I am getting expected response back.

I thought the problem is due to "Accept" header .I have tried with "*/*","application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ,But I am getting same error.

the response I am getting back in postman:

```
{
  "gatewayName": "credit-call",
  "dealerId": 1278,
  "terminalId": "jjhbjhbhjbj",
  "amount": 100,
  "orderNumber": "jhsbhjb",
  "cardNumber": "9111",
  "cardType": "Disc",
  "dateTimeInUTC": "03/01/2017 07:20:57",
  "paymentType": "EMV_CHIP",
  "authCode": "hhbjhbjh",
  "transactionReference": "asdhgwvg",
  "userReference": "bjhbjh",
  "applicationIdentiferICC": "jh2b32vy",
  "expMonth": 9,
  "expYear": 12,
  "dateTimeInPST": null,
  "inoiceGuid": null,
  "description": null
}
```

Response heades recieved after inspecting client in browser.

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: postpayment:devvm
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 15:28:17 GMT
```

I am using GWT 2.5 version.

I am getting following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty argument
    at com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:210)
    at com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser.parseStrict(JSONParser.java:87)
```

at line

```
 JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(response.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your response JSON and confirm that it is valid. The error indicates that the request is just fine, but that when the response JSON string gets to the browser `JSONParser.parseStrict(response.getText())` cannot parse it because it isn't legal JSON.

Share the response JSON and the response headers here if you need more help.

Comment: Looking good at a glance... Can you add the _exact_ error message? It doesn't look quite right, but having the stack trace and exact error might help.

Comment: added error i am getting and line at which i am getting that error.

Comment: The error message means that no JSON was present - are you very sure that `response.getText()` is the JSON you posted above? Because parseStrict wouldn't throw that exception with a non-empty string...

Comment: response.getText() is empty.the response that i posted is I am getting in postman.I am getting response.getText() empty.but I don't understood the same request with curl and postman working fine.

Comment: Ok, that's the source of your problem then. Will need a lot more detail in your question to be able to answer this, but at least start with your browser's console and network tabs in the debugger to see if there was an error in making the call, and what headers were sent to see if you did something wrong. But yes, an empty string is not valid json.